# Rollback to previous version without using Settings

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

After installing the Fall Creator's update, I recieved "Access is denied" errors whenever I tried to access certain folders. I tried every fix I could find, but none of them worked permanently.

I restarted my computer after the last try, now the start menu and search bar don't work, and the Settings app is completely broken. It opens, but the menus never load. This is a problem because to roll back, I need to go into the Update section in Settings, but the "Windows Update" menu never loads.

Is there a way to manually initiate a rollback? I can access the command prompt and other tools. The Settings app and task bar *seem* to be the only things effected.

Comment: “Is there a way to manually initiate a rollback?” - No there isn’t

Comment: accessing which folders cause the error message?

Comment: @Ramhound You're sure? I may have found a workaround anyway.

Comment: @magicandre1981 My gamesaves for Divinity (making it so I can't quicksave), and the compiler output folder for my current programming project. Seems to have messed with folders that were in use when I restarted my computer to update.

Comment: Microsoft has never documented a way to revert back to a previous installation of Windows since they announced Windows 10. I am as positive as I can be based on the information I know.

Comment: open properties of folder and give your account full permissions back.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Tried, didn't work. Despite being an administrator, it said I didn't have sufficient privileges to even view the security tab. When I tried modifying permissions on a parent folder, it would work, until the process reached the problem child, at which point I got the same error. Seems like they fubared permissions in the latest release.

Comment: next time try this tool: https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing a reset. This kept a lot of my data intact, but reinstalled Windows, and rolled me back in the process. I found a way that doesn't require the Settings app, or the taskbar:

1. Press Windows Key + X
2. Mouse over "Shutdown or signout"
3. **Hold shift**, and press "Restart". This will restart into a recovery menu
4. Press "Troubleshoot"
5. Now, there are 2 ways to go. You can try to rollback, or just reset the computer.

   - To try to rollback, from the "Troubleshoot" menu, press "Advanced Options" -> "See more recovery options" -> "Go back to a previous version"

   If that fails:

   - To reset from the "Troubleshoot" menu, press "Reset this PC", and follow the prompts.